# Referendum on official contact with the Dalai Lama?

Tags: china, referendum

Could you imagine referendums on contact with the Dalai Lama?

In which countries could it be possible with today's practices?
(I think perhaps Switzerland?).

Is it likely that it could be possible in other countries if they move to more direct democracy as advocated by many?

How would  China likely react compared to a government deciding to meet His Holiness?

I imagine the question could be something like "Should the government have official contact with the Dalai Lama or other representatives of the CTA?"

.........................

Monday: I assume of course it would be bundled with other votes.

Comment: What exactly can meeting with him achieve?

Comment: For me its mostly a moral thing.  But judging by the effort China is putting into it is important.

Comment: Do you mean the current incarnation or his successor? Because there would be serious differences between those (probably at least three) people.

Comment: I imagine the question would state somthing like "....contact with the 14th Dalai Lama or other representatives of the Tibetan government in exile"

Comment: Why do you think any country would need referendum to meet or contact with him?

Comment: I think referendums are better for real issues, such as Brexit

Comment: @rathony It an issue where where governments are out of step with the public opinion - so its a way to get what the people want.  Also the retaliation might be less (but that is a  part of the question)

Comment: Do you know when a referendum is called for in a country like Switzerland? What does contacting with Dalai Lama have to do with calling for a referendum?

Comment: @Rathony 1: No, 2: It is about "official" contact of course (Subject adjusted)

Comment: @Olav - What makes you think "governments are out of step with the public opinion"?  Do most people even care?

Comment: @Rathony, technically, they could have a referendum preventing the government to meet the Dalai Lama. And I would not put it so far beyond the UDC ideas. But yeah, essentially apart from the official position of Beijing, no one really cares.

Comment: And when would that make sense? (UDC?)

Answer (score 7):

No, I seriously could not imagine such a referendum, because for most governments the Dalai Lama is already a very welcome guest.

Here he is with US President Obama:
[image: Dalai Lama with President Obama]

Here with Angela Merkel, Chancellor of Germany:
[image: Dalai Lama with Chancellor Merkel]

He is holding hands with Prince Charles, future king of the United Kingdom and 11 other countries:
[image: Dalai Lama with Prince Charles]

And Nelson Mandela:
[image: Dalai Lama with Nelson Mandela]

Even the competition isn't afraid to be seen with him in public. Here he meets with Pope John Paul II:

[image: Dalai Lama with Pope John Paul II]

And I could post far more images of him with many more heads of states and governments.

Most of those countries where the Dalai Lama is *not* welcome are countries which do not value democracy a lot, so these are not the countries which would hold a referendum on such a matter.

But even when we assume there is a country which is democratic enough to allow a referendum on diplomatic affairs *and* doesn't want official contact with the Dalai Lama, what would such a referendum achieve? "Official Contact" doesn't mean much. Just talking with the Dalai Lama does not mean one has to listen to what he says. It's hard to mobilize the public to vote in a referendum when it is clear to them that it won't have any tangible effect on their life.

Comment: Actually more and more countries are not meeting with the Dalai Lama.  Including UK and Germany.  And in South Africa they won't even let him in.

Comment: @olav: ths is more likely to due to the increasing political influence that China has given the way its transfomed its economy.

Comment: I don't agree **for most governments the Dalai Lama is already a very welcome guest**.. And I don't think the question is on-topic. How can you possibly say **Most of those countries where the Dalai Lama is not welcome are countries which do not value democracy a lot**. Do you have any reference to support your claim?